# Disable title bar on OSX iPhone simulator

Tags: macos, mac, iphone

I often show my iOS apps on my MacBook Pro for demonstrations using the iPhone simulator. I Don't have a retina display so now when the simulator opens it looks really poor with just the square zoomed out simulator (even the new generic bezel looks nothing like as good as the old iPhone 4 proper bezel).

So what I'd like to do is have a picture of a proper iPhone bezel on my wallpaper background and show the simulator without a title bar onto so the two blend together. The problem is the simulator window has a OSX window title bar. It looks okay at the moment but would be perfect without the title bar.

I've seen references to changing the info.plist file in OSX apps to be able to disable a title bar but nothing specific - would be grateful for any input on how this could be achieved? Refuse to upgrade to a retina MacBook just for a bezel on the simulator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install EasySIMBL from https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/
- Run it, open the plugin folder.
- Download https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/154281/SimulatorBorderKiller.bundle.zip and unpack it in the plugin folder.

The SimulatorBorderKiller.bundle file is a modified version of https://github.com/ksuther/SimulatorBorderKiller where I have changed the style mask of the window with NSBorderlessWindowMask.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I also installed MercuryMover to now be able to position the Title-less simulator window with cursor keys. Looks great again within my bezel pasted onto the background wallpaper. Can't vote up as a new user.